# Simplification of a group presentation

Tags: gap, magma

Im new to MAGMA and hope somebody will help me with my question.

If a group has a presentation with 4 generators, is there a magma code/function that can give me the same group with only three generators? If so, can you please provide me with that code?

Your help with this is appropriated.
Thanks!

Comment: Considering the fact that this is not always possible, I doubt there's a general procedure.   (Consider the free abelian group on 4 generators, aka $\mathbb{Z}^4$

Comment: @Alan Thanks Alan for your answer. so let us assume it is possible, is there a code that can give me the group with fewer generators.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged it also with [gap]: GAP has a function
`IsomorphismSimplifiedFpGroup` that applies Tietze transformations heuristically, in the hope to simplify the presentation. It is likely that Magma has similar functionality.

Comment: thank you very much that would help certainly.